# Using PHP to group and display MySQL entries by weeks

Tags: php, mysql

I want to display them grouped by Month and Year, like so:

```
<p>
    <div>August 2009</div>
     <div class="fav">title 1</div>
     <div class="fav">title 5</div>
     <div class="fav">title 6</div> 
    etc...
</p>

 <p>
    <div>July 2009</div>
     <div class="fav">title 3</div>
     <div class="fav">title 8</div>
     <div class="fav">title 9</div> 
    etc...
</p>
```

Here is my query...

```
 $fav = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM links WHERE user_id='{$row['id']}' GROUP BY post_id ORDER BY id DESC");
    $TMPL = array (); $skin = new skin('mylinks/my'); $profile = '';

    while($myfav = mysql_fetch_array($fav))
    {
        $favs = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM imdb WHERE id='{$myfav['post_id']}' LIMIT 100");
            while($myfavs = mysql_fetch_array($favs))
            {   
                $TMPL['profiles'] = '<div class="fav"><a href="/movie/'.$myfavs['id'].'"><img src="/'.$myfavs['poster'].'" title="Posted '.$myfavs['date'].'" /></a></div>';
                $profile .= $skin->make();
                }           
            }
```

How would I go about grouping them, and then looping to display as above?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's your table structure? What's an "entry" for you?

Comment: Hello @Naltharial , here is my table screen http://i.imgur.com/yUBOP.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm reading it correct, you can merge the two selects and tell SQL to let you know what group they're a part of.

```
SELECT *, YEAR(`date`) AS dy, MONTH(`date`) AS dm
FROM links
LEFT JOIN imdb WHERE imdb.id = links.post_id
WHERE links.user_id='{$row['id']}'
GROUP BY links.post_id
ORDER BY links.id DESC
```

after that you can build your own group of entries.

```
$entries = array();

while($entry = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{   
    $entries[$entry['dy']][$entry['dm']] = $entry;
}
```

that should give you a three-dimensional array of entries, grouped by year and month. After that you just traverse `$entries` and display the data grouped.

Let me know if you wanted something else.